# XSL:if test or XSL:choose

Tags: xslt

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <inc_incident>
    <inc_interventionprocedure>
      <ProcedureID>CPR</ProcedureID>
    </inc_interventionprocedure>
    <inc_interventionprocedure>
      <ProcedureID>Airway-Endotracheal Intubation</ProcedureID>
    </inc_interventionprocedure>
    <inc_interventionprocedure>
      <ProcedureID>Capnography</ProcedureID>
    </inc_interventionprocedure>
  </inc_incident>
</NewDataSet>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:if test="starts-with(inc_interventionprocedure/ProcedureID, "Airway")">
 <fo:inline>X</fo:inline>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(starts-with(inc_interventionprocedure/ProcedureID, "Airway"))">
  <fo:inline>X</fo:inline>
</xsl:if>
```

I would like to show, if any of the nodes starts with "Airway", in the column "YES" with an "X" and if there is none in the column "NO" mark "X". With this xsl:if test both column is marked with Xs.

Result with the xsl:if test shows:

```
                 YES   NO
```

Airway Established    X     X

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - one we can test by copy&paste alone. Looking at your XML with a naked eye, there are several inc_interventionprocedure/ProcedureID nodes - some meet the first test, some meet the other. In addition, the XSLT snippet you show us is invalid (double quotes inside double quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by Tim C should work with a minor change as below.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="inc_interventionprocedure/ProcedureID[starts-with(., 'Airway')]">
        <fo:inline>X</fo:inline>
        <fo:inline>&nbsp;</fo:inline>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <fo:inline>&nbsp;</fo:inline>
        <fo:inline>X</fo:inline>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. It's amazing how a small change can make a difference. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your current test is not well-formed as you have quotation marks embedded inside quotation marks. But the main issue is that `starts-with` takes a string as a first parameter, not a node-set. In XSLT 1.0, it would use the value of the first node. In XSLT 2.0, you would get an error.

Your expression should really look like this

```
<xsl:if test="inc_interventionprocedure/ProcedureID[starts-with(., 'Airway')]">
```

Ideally, you would use an `xsl:choose` here to avoid writing the whole expression again inside a `not`

Try this:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="inc_interventionprocedure/ProcedureID[starts-with(., 'Airway')]">
            <fo:inline>YES</fo:inline>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:inline>NO</fo:inline>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

This assumes you are positioned on a `inc_incident` element.

Comment: "*But the main issue is ..*" That would **not** produce the claimed result.